# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=undefined):

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to change the status of my blog from draft to published and vice-versa.
It is working with the page reload but I would like to implement with ajax.

Here is my 
blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle_status]

  # GET /blogs
  # GET /blogs.json
  def index
    # @blog = Blog.new
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  # GET /blogs/1
  # GET /blogs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /blogs/new
  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  # GET /blogs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /blogs
  # POST /blogs.json
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /blogs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /blogs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.update(blog_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /blogs/1
  # DELETE /blogs/1.json
   def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to blogs_url, notice: 'Blog was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end

   def toggle_status
    # @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.draft?
       @blog.published!
    elsif @blog.published?
       @blog.draft!
    end 

    redirect_to blogs_url, notice: "Blog status has been updated"
   end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :status)
    end
end
```

Here is my
 blog.rb

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { draft: 0, published:1 }
end
```

Here is my
index.html.erb

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= blog.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to blog.status,toggle_status_blog_path(blog), remote: true, class: "test" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Here is my
application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.test").on( "click", function( event ) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/blogs/" + id + "/toggle_status",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(r){

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my
routes.rb

```
resources :blogs do 
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end
```

I tried too hard but I am not getting the desired results.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something's wrong with your JS, since `id` is `undefined`. I suggest you debug there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=undefined)

You have `var id = $(this).attr("id");` but you haven't defined `id` attribute in the link. So `$(this).attr("id")` is **undefined** which further constructs url like `"/blogs/undefined/toggle_status"`. So the `:id` is passed as `undefined` to the query `Blog.find(params[:id])` which fails with that exception. To fix your problem define the `id` like so

```
<%= link_to blog.status,toggle_status_blog_path(blog), remote: true, class: "test", id: blog.id %>
```

**Note:**

If your Jquery version is **>= 1.6**, then `attr` is deprecated for 1.6 and later versions. You should `prop` instead of `attr`

```
var id = $(this).prop("id");
```

**Update: #1**

The action is performing twice. That is because you are performing the same **AJAX** call twice! One with `remote:true` in the link and the other with Jquery AJAX. You should keep either of the one and remove the other. So the final answer would be just this

```
<%= link_to blog.status,toggle_status_blog_path(blog), remote: true, class: "test" %>
```

**Update #2:**

As your final goal is to display the updated status of a blog on instant(i.e, without refreshing the page), then you need to follow the below steps

1) Change the the `link_to` as

```
<%= link_to blog.status, "javascript:void(0);", class: "test", id: blog.id %>
```

2) Bring back your Jquery code. We need it now. Add the necessary code in the `success` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.test").on( "click", function( event ) {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var current_link = $(this)

  $.ajax({
    url: "/blogs/" + id + "/toggle_status",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(r){
      console.log(r["blog_status"]);
      current_link.text(r["blog_status"]); // this will display the status of the blog
      alert("Blog status has been updated");
     }
  });
  });
});
```

3) Change your `toggle_status` method to below

```
def toggle_status
  if @blog.draft?
    @blog.published!
  elsif @blog.published?
    @blog.draft!
  end 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to blogs_url, notice: "Blog status has been updated"}
    format.json { render json: {blog_status: @blog.status, status: :ok }}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I place id: "<%= blog.id %>" in my link_to because it is throwing me the error.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '>' ...output_buffer.safe_append='" %></td>

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen My bad! Updated the answer. It should be just `id: blog.id`

Comment: Thanks got escape from the error. But toggling not working but in my console it shows as : Blog Update (1.1ms)  UPDATE "blogs" SET "status" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "blogs"."id" = ?  [["status", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-10-16 07:43:31.343122"], ["id", 3]]

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen the console log is right! Check the blog with id 3. Its status should be published.

Comment: Yes it is, one more problem when it toggle the status from the browser, the update query runs twice in the server making cancellation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181931/discussion-between-pavan-and-muhammad-yaseen).

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen I've updated my answer as per our discussion over the chat :)

Comment: We specified the route for link_to as "#" and therefore status gets updated one time and get stuck there onwards and then no toggling.Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Can you come here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182012/room-for-pavan-and-muhammad-yaseen